# Is there an out of the box way to bind the entire body of an HTTP request to a string parameter in an ASP.NET Core controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

## Summary

Given an HTTP request with a string body "hamburger"
I want to be able to bind the entire body of the request to a string parameter in the controller action's method signature.

When calling this controller by making an HTTP request to the relative URL `string-body-model-binding-example/get-body` I get an error and the action is never called

### Controller

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProject
{
    [Route("string-body-model-binding-example")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ExampleController: ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPut("get-body")]
        public string GetRequestBody(string body)
        {
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

### Integration Test Demonstrating the Problem

```cs
using FluentAssertions;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

public class MyIntegrationTests : MyIntegrationTestBase
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task String_body_is_bound_to_the_actions_body_parameter()
    {
        var body = "hamburger";
        var uri = "string-body-model-binding-example/get-body";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        };

        var result = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request); 
        var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseBody.Should().Be(body,
            "The body should have been bound to the controller action's body parameter");
    }
}
```

Note: in the above example test HttpClient is setup using [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1. My other controller actions with a [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object) model in the action method signature are reachable so I know there is something wrong with how I am trying to do my model binding.

Edit: Things I've tried:

- Adding [FromBody] to the parameter => 415 Unsupported Media type
- Removing [ApiController] from the controller => Action is hit but body is null
- Adding [FromBody] to the parameter and removing [ApiController] from the controller => 415 Unsupported Media type
- Adding [Consumes("text/plain")] to action w/wout [ApiController] and w/wout [FromBody]
- Sending the request with a content type of application/json with any of the above combinations => error or null depending on the option

It surprises me that string isn't one of the [supported primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#simple-types)

Comment: Have you tried using the `[FromBody]` attribute on the argument?

Comment: Yeah I get a 415 Unsupported Media type with [FromBody] and a 400 Bad Request without it.

Comment: I suggest not using a parameter at all and just reading the body from `Request.Body` (you'll need a `StreamReader`).

Comment: @PaulStegler ApiController accepts `application/json` by default. not `text/plain`. You example is trying to post plain text which is unsupported.

Comment: @Nkosi sending the request as application/json still doesn't work with any combination of using ApiController or not, paired with or without form data.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am fine manually grabbing the request body but It would be nice if the framework handled that for me. I guess it opens up the api to attack a little since it would allow callers to send over a huge body, forcing the service to parse it all but shouldn't the framework protect against that too in an ideal world?

Comment: Docs shows that string is not a support simple type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#simple-types-1 that can bind by default from the body

Comment: @HereticMonkey ASP.NET Core does put a limit on body size by default FYI. This article about it looks pretty good https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/#:~:text=ASP.NET%20Core%202.0%20enforces,increase%20the%20default%20allowed%20limit.

Comment: ... Sorry, what? I made a couple brief comments a year ago. I know of the limits ASP.NET Core puts on requests. I was just pointing out a couple of ways that might get you up and running quick...

Comment: I misread the comment history and was clarifying something past me said but I thought you had said it @HereticMonkey. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this possible to achieve with the framework means but you can create a custom model binder for this

```
public class RawBodyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            string result = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
[HttpPut("get-body")]
public string GetRequestBody([ModelBinder(typeof(RawBodyModelBinder))] string body)
{
    return body;
}
```

Or you can tell the framework to use your model binder in more elegant way using `IModelBinderProvider`. First introduce new `BindingSource` as a singleton

```
public static class CustomBindingSources
{
    public static BindingSource RawBody { get; } = new BindingSource("RawBod", "Raw Body", true, true);
}
```

And create our `[FromRawBody]` attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FromRawBodyAttribute : Attribute, IBindingSourceMetadata
{
    public BindingSource BindingSource => CustomBindingSources.RawBody;
}
```

The framework treats `IBindingSourceMetadata` attributes in special way and gets its `BindingSource` value for us so it can be used in model binder provider.

Then create `IModelBinderProvider`

```
public class RawBodyModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        //use binder if parameter is string
        //and FromRawBody specified
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string) && 
            context.BindingInfo.BindingSource == CustomBindingSources.RawBody)
        {
            return new RawBodyModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Add the model binder provider in `Startup`

```
services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new RawBodyModelBinderProvider());
        //..
    }
```

Use it as the following

```
[HttpPut("get-body")]
public string GetRequestBody([FromRawBody] string body)
{
    return body;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. If someone didn't want the complexity of the model binder, as @HereticMonkey said, you can just stream the Request.Body and read it as a string from the controller in the same way as is done in the RawBodyModelBinder class in this answer.